# Install nextcloud with different data dierectory

Tags: owncloud, nextcloud

I dont know whether this is possible or not, but what I want is, I want to install next cloud in my raspberry pi and I know how to install and I want to target the mysql database which is installed in a different server and I know how to do this as well, but my question is, I want to change the data directory to complete new server, for example, my raspberry pi has only 16gb memory card, so I have secondary linux server which contains 2TB of hard disk and also mysql is also installed in this 2TB server, so I want the data to be kept in this new 2TB server instead of raspberry. So is it possible?

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated....

Comment: `I want to target the mysql database which is installed in a different server and I know how to do this as well` .... if you already know how to do that, then what is your question? ... You already know that it is possible.

Comment: `I want the data to be kept in this new 2TB server instead of raspberry` this is my question.

Comment: you said in your post that you know how to target the mysql database on a different server .... the 2TB server is a different server .... still no idea what you are asking, but you accepted an answer ... good luck

Comment: Man, data directory and database connection are two different things, please see the configuration page of owncloud and nextcloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By installing a NFS server on the other server with 2TB storage you can export a directory of this server and mount it on the raspberry pi.

To install the NFS server on Debian (or raspbian) follow e.g. this tutorial https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-configure-nfs-on-debian-9-stretch-linux or any other tutorial on the web.

The ArchWiki also has good documentation on NFS: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS.

You can change the data directory of Nextcloud using the `datadirectory` configuration option in the `config/config.php` file. Please be careful when changing the datadir when Nextcloud is already installed, this may give some weird problems.